# SQL Copy data from table to another and count value

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010, sql-insert

I am stuck at the moment. I am creating a sports database in MS Access for our sports club and have the following question...

So what I have:
Tbl_Player (Player_ID, Firstname, Lastname, position, Min_Played, Goal, Assist, Yellow, Red)

Tbl_Player_Match (FK Tbl_Player_Player_ID, Min_Played, Goal, Assist, Yellow, Red).

What I need and strugling on is the following. When I add a match and data is being saved in tbl_Player_Match, I would need to have this saved in the "Summary" table which is Tbl_Player.

I cannot find the right syntax for this, should I create another temp table with the stats? Should I simply add an SQL code here?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Bob

Comment: please provide sample data with expected output in table structure

Comment: For example: tbl_Player_Match (Min_Played) = 90, this would need to be saved in tbl_Player (Min_Played). But when there is another match and assuming tbl_Player (Min_Played) is 90 and again in tbl_Player (Min_Played) is again 90, the tbl_Player (Min_PLayed) would be 180.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd strongly suggest just using a query to pull the totals at run time:

```
SELECT  ID
        , Naam
        , Achtenaam
        , SUM(Goals) as Total
FROM    Speler LEFT JOIN SpelerStats ON Speler.ID = SpelerStats.Speler
GROUP BY ID
        , Naam
        , Achtenaam
```

If you must add it to the table you'll have to use a [domain aggregate function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Expressions-684295d0-97c2-443c-8e0a-8c6b635bec56#ID0EAABAAA=Domain):

```
UPDATE  Speler
SET     Total = DSUM("Goals","SpelerStats","SpelerStats.Speler = " & Speler.ID)
```

Comment: This is exactly where I am after! Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I would tell you that you shouldn't store a summed value in tbl_Player. There comes only the characteristics of a Player for instance Name, Position and so on. 
For the Output you create a query that would go something like this:

`Select p.Player_ID, p.Firsname, p.Lastname, p.position, SUM(pm.Min_Played) as Sum_Min_Played
//, Count(pm.Tbl_Player_Match_ID) as Matches_Played 
From
Tbl_Player p inner join Tbl_Player_Match pm on p.Player_ID = pm.Tbl_Player_Player_ID
group by p.Player_ID, p.Firsname, p.Lastname, p.position`

The Matches_Played is just an addition, if you have sth. like an ID for the Matches Table.
Tell me if it helped you.

Comment: Hi Nebi! Thanks a lot for your comment. So what you are saying storing the summary of Min_Played shouldnt be added to the table?

Comment: yes, I wouldn't do it. The question is why you want to do that. Because the DB always has to update the Tbl_Player. This shown way the DB doesn't have to update the Tbl_Player. Only If something changes with the players attributes.

Comment: Hi, I am sorry but that isnt really what I am looking for.